# Sphinx documentation locally works, but not on read the docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I started with writing my documentation for my lil' python/django project.

This happens:

```
Running Sphinx v1.2
loading translations [en]... done
building [readthedocs]: targets for 18 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 18 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [  5%] administrator-guide/customizing
reading sources... [ 11%] administrator-guide/index
reading sources... [ 16%] developer-guide/index
reading sources... [ 22%] index
reading sources... [ 27%] modules/booking
Sphinx Standard Error
Sphinx error:
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 475: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I understand, this is an encoding problem.

But: all my files are encoded with UTF-8. AND it works locally (windows).

This is my [modules/booking.rst](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omeinusch/Palco/issue-109-documentation/docs/modules/booking.rst). And [in this directory are my booking-module-files](https://github.com/omeinusch/Palco/tree/issue-109-documentation/engine/booking).

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), adding this to the top of your source file ensures it works properly with utf-8 encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Personally hit this snag when I had some Japanese characters in a string literal in a source file.

Comment: Well, this is crazy. I added encoding=utf-8 to all files and now it works. even in these files were none characters utf8-only. nevertheless. Thank you!